# Existance proofs with polymorphic types

Tags: isabelle, theorem-proving, automaton

I am trying to formalize the proof that DFA are closed under union, and I have got so far as proving `"∀  ℬ. language  ∪ language ℬ = language (DFA_union  ℬ)"`, but what I would actually like to prove is `∀  ℬ. ∃ . language  ∪ language ℬ = language` . I belive the issue has something to do with polymorphic types, but I am not sure.

Here is what I have:

```
declare [[show_types]]
declare [[show_sorts]]
declare [[show_consts]]

record ('q, 'a)DFA =
  Q0 :: 'q
  F :: "'q set"
  δ :: "'q ⇒ 'a ⇒ 'q"

primrec δ_iter :: "('q, 'a)DFA ⇒ 'a list ⇒ 'q ⇒ 'q" where
  "δ_iter  [] q = q" |
  "δ_iter  (a # as) q = δ_iter  as (δ  q a)"

definition δ0_iter :: "('q, 'a)DFA ⇒ 'a list ⇒ 'q" where
  "δ0_iter  as = δ_iter  as (Q0 )"

definition language :: "('q, 'a)DFA ⇒ ('a list) set" where
  "language  = {w . δ0_iter  w ∈ (F )}"

fun DFA_union :: "('p, 'a)DFA ⇒ ('q, 'a)DFA ⇒ ('p × 'q, 'a)DFA" where
  "DFA_union  ℬ = 
    ⦇ Q0 = (Q0 , Q0 ℬ)
    , F = {(q, r) . q ∈ F  ∨ r ∈ F ℬ}
    , δ = λ (q, r). λ a. (δ  q a, δ ℬ r a) 
    ⦈"

lemma extract_fst: "∀  ℬ p q. fst (δ_iter (DFA_union  ℬ) ws (p, q)) = δ_iter  ws p" 
  by (induct ws; simp)

lemma extract_snd: "∀  ℬ p q. snd (δ_iter (DFA_union  ℬ) ws (p, q)) = δ_iter ℬ ws q" 
  by (induct ws; simp)

lemma "∀  ℬ. language  ∪ language ℬ = language (DFA_union  ℬ)"
proof((rule allI)+)
  fix  ℬ
  let ? = "DFA_union  ℬ"
  have "language ? = {w . δ0_iter ? w ∈ F ?}" 
    by (simp add: language_def)
  also have "... = {w . fst (δ0_iter ? w) ∈ (F ) ∨ snd (δ0_iter ? w) ∈ (F ℬ)}" 
    by auto 
  also have "... = {w . δ0_iter  w ∈ F  ∨ δ0_iter ℬ w ∈ F ℬ}"
    using DFA.select_convs(1) DFA_union.simps δ0_iter_def extract_fst extract_snd
    by (metis (no_types, lifting)) 
  also have "... = {w . δ0_iter  w ∈ F } ∪ {w. δ0_iter ℬ w ∈ F ℬ}"
    by blast
  also have "... = language  ∪ language ℬ"
    by (simp add: language_def)
  finally show "language  ∪ language ℬ = language ?"
    by simp
qed

lemma DFA_union_closed: "∀  ℬ. ∃ . language  ∪ language ℬ = language "
  sorry
```

If I add types to  or ℬ in the main lemma I get "Failed to refine any pending goal".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is indeed because of implicit types. In your last statement Isabelle implicitly infers state-types `'p, 'q, 'r` for the three automata `A, B, C`,
whereas your `DFA_union` lemma fixes the state type of `C` to `'p * 'q`. Therefore, if you have to explicitly provide type-annotations. Moreover, it is usually not required to state your lemmas with explicit `∀`-quantifiers.

So, you can continue like this:

```
lemma DFA_union: "language  ∪ language ℬ = language (DFA_union  ℬ)" 
  (is "_ = language ?")
proof -
   have "language ? = {w . δ0_iter ? w ∈ F ?}" 
   ...
qed

lemma DFA_union_closed: fixes  :: "('q,'a)DFA" and ℬ :: "('p,'a)DFA"
  shows "∃  :: ('q × 'p, 'a)DFA. language  ∪ language ℬ = language "
  by (intro exI, rule DFA_union)
```

Note that these type-annotations are also essential in the following sense.
A lemma like the following (where all state-types are the same) is just not true.

```
lemma fixes  :: "('q,'a)DFA" and ℬ :: "('q,'a)DFA"
  shows "∃  :: ('q, 'a)DFA. language  ∪ language ℬ = language "
```

The problem is, plug in the `bool`-type for `'q`, then you have automata which
have at most two states. And then you cannot always find an automaton for the union that also has at most two states.

Comment: Thanks for that! The only unsatisfactory thing is that the `∃  :: ('q × 'p, 'a)DFA.` still "gives away" how the automaton is constructed.